# Android: How to get java and xml files from my mobile phone?

Tags: android

I have been working on an application for several weeks now but this evening (after having uploading my Android Studio), all the java and xml files were corrupted (one java file fulled with "NaN", another cut halfway, etc.) I don't have a clue about what happened but I would like to go on my project. The latest version of the app is on my mobile phone (I tested it and I was so happy it worked well). Could I have any chance to get back project files from my mobile phone ?

Thanks

Comment: Uff da. Source control, external backups... no better time to learn about and use them.

Comment: I think use clean project option in eclipse. Or you can decompile apk file .